# Setting up SSL on an Apache Ubuntu Server

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

I am setting up an SSL certificate for the first time on an Ubuntu server. I have purchased a dedicated IP address and have purchased the certificate under the subdomain of secure.example.com

Port 443 is open and being listened to by apache and using an online server to check the secure.example.com domain shows that the certificate appears to be setup and working fine. Here is my config for the domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ..
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 109.228.x.x:443>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ServerName secure.example.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/secure.example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/secure.example.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/Intermediate.crt

    <Directory "/var/www/example.com">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

However when I go to https://secure.example.com it redirects to http://secure.example.com displaying the default "It works!" page since it isn't configured. I cannot see anything in any error logs and I am not sure where to go from here.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you disable original httpd.conf?

Comment: the httpd.conf file on the server is blank

Comment: What is the output of apache2ctl -S ? And what do you see in your access logs?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/83RuWCdA
 
VirtualHost configuration:
109.228.x.x:443     secure.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example:34)
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server server109-228-x-y.servers.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost server109-228-x-y.servers.net (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost example2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example2:1)
         port 80 namevhost example3.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example3:1)
Syntax OK

Comment: also access.log entry:  82.69.x.x - - [26/Apr/2013:16:38:14 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 693 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31"

Comment: What content is in `/var/www/example.com`?  Apache is not configured to redirect, so you probably have application code that's configured to point to a specific "canonical" URL, and is redirecting requests that don't match that.  Or you have an htaccess file configured to redirect.

Comment: do you have a `.htaccess` file in the /var/www/example.com ?